# uso de Sum SQL SERVER

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Necesito sumar todo lo que hay en valor ;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi query

```
create procedure sp_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado @inicio datetime, @final datetime, @emp int
as
select 
ded.DedId,
sum(ded.DetDedEmpValor),
emp.EmpId


from Tbl_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado ded
inner join Tbl_Deducciones tip
 on tip.DedId = ded.DedId
 inner join Tbl_Empleado emp
 on emp.EmpId = ded.EmpId
 where ded.DetDedEmpFecha >=  @inicio and 
 ded.DetDedEmpFecha <= @final and 
 ded.EmpId = @emp
 group by ded.DedId, emp.EmpId



execute sp_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado '2018-05-01', '2018-05-08', '2390'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para ello debes embeber tu select inicial, dentro de un select mayor de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT SUM(X.SumValor)  -- Sumas la columna especificada
FROM(
    select 
        ded.DedId,
        sum(ded.DetDedEmpValor) AS 'SumValor',  -- Aquí debes ponerle un alias
        emp.EmpId
    from Tbl_DetalleDeduccionesEmpleado ded
    inner join Tbl_Deducciones tip
        on tip.DedId = ded.DedId
    inner join Tbl_Empleado emp
        on emp.EmpId = ded.EmpId
    where ded.DetDedEmpFecha >=  @inicio and 
        ded.DetDedEmpFecha <= @final and 
        ded.EmpId = @emp
    group by ded.DedId, emp.EmpId
) AS X
```

**NOTA:** también puedes hacer uso de un **CTE** para este tipo de situaciones. Saludos.